# Apply template arguments to function without calling function?

Tags: d

How do I apply just the template arguments to a function that expects template arguments, without implicitly also calling the function with zero arguments? I want a function or delegate pointer instead of a value.

```
void foo(T)(double x) {}

auto bar() {
    return foo!(int);
}
```

```
hack.d(36): Error: function hack.foo!int.foo(double x) is not callable using argument types ()
hack.d(36):        missing argument for parameter #1: double x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had an ordinary function

```
void foo() {}
```

and you wanted a function pointer to it, how would you do that?

```
&foo
```

Now, suppose you have a template:

```
void foo(T)() {}
```

and want a pointer to a specific instance... you can probably guess at this point :)

```
&foo!arg
```

Comment: Compile-Time, not delegate `alias bar = foo!int;`